# Cannot clone object keras.wrappers

Tags: machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn, deep-learning, data-science

```
      def try_and_error(layers, activation):
         model = Sequential()
         for i, nodes in enumerate(layers):
            if i==0:
                model.add(Dense(nodes,input_dim=train_X.shape[1]))#input layers 

                model.add(Activation(activation)) #Activation layer
            else:
                model.add(Dense(nodes))# Hidden Layers
                model.add(Activation(activation))#Activation Layers
          model.add(Dense(1)) # output layer

     model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model



    layers=[[150], [160,100], [140,100,500]]
    activations = ['sigmoid', 'relu']
    param_grid = dict(layers=layers, activation=activations, batch_size= 
    [500,800,1000])
    grid = 
    RandomizedSearchCV(
                      estimator=KerasClassifier(build_fn=try_and_error
                                                ,epochs=100,verbose=0), 
                      param_distributions =param_grid)


     grid_result= grid.fit(train_X,train_y)}
```

and this is the error encountered even I have tried this with gridsearchcv result still the same. 
`RuntimeError: Cannot clone object <keras.wrappers.scikit_learn.KerasClassifier object at 0x7f3d7959c390>`, as the constructor either does not set or modifies parameter layers

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest

Comment: Sklearn uses `clone`method to create another copy of estimator. But if your estimator is a keras dependent estimator then `clone`fails. To get around this you could either override the clone method from sklearn ( that's difficult) or construct a custom class to train your keras model but keep the `init`of your custom class free from any keras objects.

Comment: please suggest the needful here in code,urgently needed

Comment: it may help you:
https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/66341/cannot-clone-object-keras-wrappers-scikit-learn-kerasregressor-object-at-0x7fdc it is a bug related to nested lists!

Answer (score 3):

Try replacing

```py
layers=[[150], [160,100], [140,100,500]]
```

with

```py
layers=[(150), (160,100), (140,100,500)]
```

Comment: Explain why it fixes the issue.

Answer (score 1):

change the layers to this :
`layers=[(150,), (160,100), (140,100,500)]`

Also , Dont forget to add (,) in (150,) otherwise it will throw an error like : TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
This is because single tuple without comma(,) is treated as int.